# move file by list in file (with leading whitespace)

Tags: shell-script, files, rename

I have a file that contains file names. For example:

`/tmp/list.txt` (it is with the spaces at the start of each line):

```
  /tmp/file.log
  /app/nir/home.txt
  /etc/config.cust
```

I want, using one line, to move all the files listed in `/tmp/list.txt` to `/app/dest`

So it should be something like this:

```
cat /tmp/list.txt | xargs mv /app/dest/
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are just missing the `-t` option for `mv` (assuming GNU `mv`):

```
cat /tmp/list.txt | xargs mv -t /app/dest/
```

or shorter (inspired by X Tian's answer):

```
xargs mv -t /app/dest/ < /tmp/list.txt
```

the leading (and possible trailing) spaces are removed. Spaces within the filenames will lead to problems.

If you have spaces or tabs or quotes or backslashes in the filenames, assuming GNU `xargs` you can use:

```
sed 's/^ *//' < /tmp/list.txt | xargs -d '\n' mv -t /app/dest/
```

Comment: Thank you , for the answer . with this i can make a list of lot of files with [!] in their name , and move to another folder , with the follow :

ls | grep -e ".[!]]" | tee 001.txt ; sed 's/^ *//' < 001.txt | xargs -d '\n' mv -t /destinypath/

Comment: These don't work on OS X. "mv: illegal option -- t"

Comment: @JohnSmith OS X is not using GNU versions of these utilities, AFAIK they use BSD versions which in general have fewer fancy options.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your file names are relatively sane (no newlines or weird characters):

```
while read file; do mv "$file" /app/dest/; done < list.txt
```

To deal with weird file names (breaks if a file name has a newline):

```
while IFS= read -r file; do mv "$file" /app/dest/; done < list.txt
```

Comment: Hi terdon, how to move folders into new directory based on their match in the csv file? Could you please help me with this [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433068/move-the-folders-into-a-new-directory-based-on-the-folder-names-in-a-file] Thank you !!

Comment: @user3351523 your question has been closed. Asking random people for help won't change that. Instead, edit the question, and explain how the solutions in the duplicate didn't help you. If something "didn't work", explain how it failed. The solutions should work for you, so you need to explain what happens when you try them.

Comment: I did that. you can have a look.

Comment: @user3351523 you haven't explained why the solutions of the dupe fail for you. And you haven't explained how the answers you have gotten fail. You might just need to use `cp -Hr` but I don't know if OSX `cp` supports that.

Comment: Nope. On OS X (Mojave, at least), both these command lines do absolutely nothing at all.

Comment: @JohnSmith there is nothing here that isn't portable. If the commands fail, the paths in `list.txt` must be wrong. You can check by adding an echo: `while IFS= read -r file; do echo mv "$file" /app/dest/; done < list.txt `

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in $(cat /tmp/list.txt); do mv "$i" /app/dest/; done
```

Comment: Can't handle spaces in filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Pure xargs reading directly from file

```
xargs -l -i < flist  mv -v {} /app/dst
```

edit 1 -- after @Anthon 's comment below,

```
xargs -I{} < flist  mv -v {} /app/dst
```

edit 2 -- after @John Smith comment below

```
xargs -I{} < flist mv -v "{}" /app/dst
```

Quoting *replace-str* (see `man xargs` for explanation of *replace-str*) ensures filenames with blanks are treated as one argument. Newline becomes the input field terminator. However blank lines are ignored.

-I{} Implies the field separator is newline, and implies -L1 (use max one line for each output invocation). So `mv` is invoked for each input line.

Comment: `-i` is deprecrated, and it, or it replacement -I imply `-l`/`--max-lines=1`. And it causes `mv` to be executed for each file separately.

Comment: Nope. "mv: rename {} to /app/dst/{}: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

```
mv `cat /tmp/list.txt` /app/dest/
```

(spaces at start are ignored)

Comment: Can't handle spaces in filenames.